# Hide Blanks in Data Validation with nested if. Excel

Tags: excel-formula

Love the offset formula to avoid blanks cells but i have 5 **nested IF** in Data validation so if i use above offset formula, it doesnt allow me as there are limited characters space

Below is my formula, so anyname in without "" is table (range)

```
=IF(A17="WATER",WATER,IF(A17="SPORT",SPORT,IF(A17="JUICE",JUICE,IF(A17="SOFT_DRINK__MIXERS__MINERAL_WATERS",SOFT_DRINK__MIXERS__MINERAL_WATERS,IF(A17="CORDIAL",CORDIAL,IF(A17="POSTMIX",POSTMIX,MONSTER))))))
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why doesn't the above formula work?

Answer (score 0):

You actually have a six level nested if and adding the OFFSET would bring it to 7

You can nest formulas up to seven levels.  My thought here is that you have nested six levels of IFs and if you are nesting that into an OFFSET Formula then you are hitting the limitation of Excel and that would be why it is not working.  Is it possible to break the IFs into two parts so that each one is nested three levels deep and have your offset key off the second half.

EX.

```
CELL A1:  =IF(cond1,range1,IF(cond2,range2,IF(cond3,range3,IF(cond4,range4,value_marker))))
CELL A2:  =IF(A1=value_marker,IF(cond5,range5,IF(cond6,range6,default)),default)
```

I think that would work if I understood your question properly.